# Custom event listener example in Grails documentation

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, bootstrapping

I'm trying to add a custom GORM event listener class in `Bootstrap.groovy`, as described in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) but its not working for me. Here is the code straight from the docs:

```
def init = {
    application.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { k, datastore ->
        applicationContext.addApplicationListener new MyPersistenceListener(datastore)
    }
}
```

When I run it, the compiler complains that application and applicationContext are null. I've tried adding them as class level members but they don't get magically wired up service-style. The closest I've got so far is:

```
def grailsApplication
def init = { servletContext ->
    def applicationContext = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    grailsApplication.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { k, datastore ->
        applicationContext.addApplicationListener new GormEventListener(datastore)
    }
}
```

But I still get errors: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object`.

Thanks for reading...

EDIT: version 2.2.1

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: According to the docs for [EventTriggeringInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/EventTriggeringInterceptor.html), you need to be at least with 2.0.

Comment: Added version to Q...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do:

```
ctx.getBeansOfType(Datastore).values().each { Datastore d ->
   ctx.addApplicationListener new MyPersistenceListener(d)
}
```

This should work without needing the Hibernate plugin installed

Answer (score 5):

That looks like it should work, although I'd do it a bit differently. BootStrap.groovy does support dependency injection, so you can inject the `grailsApplication` bean, but you can also inject `eventTriggeringInterceptor` directly:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication
   def eventTriggeringInterceptor

   def init = { servletContext ->
      def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
      eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.values().each { datastore ->
         ctx.addApplicationListener new MyPersistenceListener(datastore)
      }
   }
}
```

Here I still inject `grailsApplication` but only because I need access to the `ApplicationContext` to register listeners. Here's my listener (simpler than what the docs claim the simplest implementation would be btw ;)

```
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener

class MyPersistenceListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

   MyPersistenceListener(Datastore datastore) {
      super(datastore)
   }

   protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
      println "Event $event.eventType $event.entityObject"
   }

   boolean supportsEventType(Class eventType) { true }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just tried it and `eventTriggeringInterceptor` is null (Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object) - IntelliJ IDEA also does not show `eventTriggeringInterceptor` as being wired (no bean icon next to it). I just noticed that my app does not have the Hibernate plugin installed (we are using MongoDB GORM), could that explain it?

Comment: Added Hibernate plugin and it works - but I don't want the hibernate plugin - looks like a legacy bug maybe?

Comment: Hibernate plugin is also breaking GORM findAll calls by trying to do a hibernate lookup, despite my DataSource.groovy having no hibernate code in it. I'm seeing `Table "PROJECT" not found; SQL statement` now. Also the docs state in the following section (Hibernate Events): "It is generally encouraged to use the non-Hibernate specific API described above" - so this code should not depend on Hibernate IMHO. EDIT: or it is a Mongodb plugin bug, which is expected to inject `eventTriggeringInterceptor` into `mainContext`???

Answer (score 1):

Finally stumbled onto a working `Bootstrap.groovy`, thanks to [this post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Getting-the-datastore-in-a-grails-2-0-1-project-td4521590.html) but I don't think its the best way to do it, rather its a work around.

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def applicationContext = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    applicationContext.addApplicationListener new GormEventListener(applicationContext.mongoDatastore)
}
```

So basically I'm hard-coding the MongoDB datastore directly as opposed to iterating over the available ones, as the docs suggest.

To save you reading the comments to the first answer, the adapted version I provided in the Question (as well as Burt's answer) only works if the **Hibernate plugin** is installed but in my case I was using the **MongoDB plugin** so had no need for the Hibernate plugin (it in fact broke my app in other ways).