# HibernateEventListeners not catching events

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails project using GORM.

I need to post-insert events using hibernates event listener. Here is my class

```
class PersistenceListener implements PostInsertEventListener {

@Override
void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent postInsertEvent) {
    println("postInsert")
    println(postInsertEvent)
    println(postInsertEvent.entity)
}
```

And here is my resources.xml : 
    beans = {

```
persistenceListener(PersistenceListener)

hibernateEventListeners(HibernateEventListeners) {
  listenerMap = ['post-insert': persistenceListener]
}
```

}

I have two datastores. One is using mysql and one is using mongodb. The strange thing is that the listener is catching the events going to mysql but isn't catching the mongodb events. I have no idea why. Cn anyone shed some light on the issue? Maybe its because I have two datastores?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I'm fairly sure that GORM doesn't use hibernate for mongodb

Comment: Really? There must be something in between the two when calling Domain.save() ?

Comment: Well, I think when you call Domain.save(), it's the mongo plugin that persists the data to mongodb. The [docs](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/1.%20Introduction.html#1.1%20Compatibility%20with%20GORM%20for%20Hibernate) seem to suggest that they've tried to provide an api that's consistent with the gorm/hibernate api, without it actually being hibernate.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I wasn't aware that it wasn't using hibernate itself. That must be where the issue is. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the mongodb plugin provides an implementation of PersistenceInterceptor that you could hook into...?

Comment: @rcgeorge23 Could you transform it in an answer?

Comment: Ok, I've added my comments as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GORM doesn't use Hibernate to talk to MongoDB, so unfortunately you won't be able use Hibernate's event listener API to hook into MongoDB persistence events.

There's [another stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913877/custom-event-listener-example-in-grails-documentation) that demonstrates how to register listeners for arbitrary GORM events. Perhaps you could try something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) instead? For example:

```
class YourDomainClass {

  def afterInsert() { 
    // stuff to do after saving a new instance goes here
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ye the problem was with the afterInsert event. I'm working on archival functionilaty and need to do a lookup on the newly inserted object in the afterInsert block. The issue was that the object isn't in the database yet when afterInsert is called. Therefore I was examining the hibernate events to see if it could be done there.

Comment: Based on the name, I'd expect the object to be persisted by the time `afterInsert` is called. If you want to track inserts/updates/deletes to domain classes you might find using the audit logging plugin a simpler approach: http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging

Comment: As did I..afterInsert is called as part of the save transaction. The object won't be found in the database until the transaction is complete. So no joy :(